# Continuity bug in the Tour

Tags: bug, design, tour

Here we see the first section of the tour (English Language & Usage), with an accepted answer by Robusto, and 4 up votes.

[image]

The we scroll down, to the 5th section - about "editing and commenting"

Here his answer, now with 9 up votes. But it hasn't been accepted?

[image]

This is the same on all sites I believe:

Ask Ubuntu:

[image]

[image]

This is inconsistent, either the votes shouldn't change (it's a snapshot in time) or the accept should still be there.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see it as a bug. Reasons being:

- Screenshots on the Tour page are not supposed to show/depict the timeline of a post.
- Screenshots only contain limited UI/functionality elements. Features which are explained in the accompanying text are included in the screenshots. No need to show irrelevant pieces to the new user, helps them to focus on the relevant features.

For example, the first screenshot is about *questions*, *answers*, *votes*, and *accepted answer*. Which is why the *edit* link has been omitted from there. Similarly, the other screen explains *edit* and *add comment* links, so the green checkmark has been removed from that one.

Comment: So why do the votes change? If it was a snapshot in time, the votes would be the same, except in the voting section, where they would change.

Comment: @Tim I think they took another screenshot, they have not used one snapshot in time. Which is the reason votes/score is different (increased during the time duration of first screenshot and the second). Second screenshot was taken to show a comment (which was not present in the first screenshot).

Comment: Yeah, but the question was accepted @ 4 votes, and the second one is 9 votes - it has gone up, but been unaccepted in that time?

Comment: I guess they just added the green checkmark to convey the concept.

Comment: Okay - still seems odd that it disappears... I see why it does, but that doesn't mean it should.